# GCD Proof with Unique inverses

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm given a problem stating:

> If $\gcd(m,x) = 1$ then $x$ has a unique inverse modulo $m$.

I'm told to state and prove the converse, which I believe is:

$$ x \text{ has a unique inverse modulo } m  \implies \gcd( m, x ) = 1$$

After that step I'm sort of stuck. I know for gcd to equal $1$ you must end up with:

$$ma + xb = 1$$

Comment: Hint: any common divisor of $\,m,x\,$ divides the LHS of the final equation, so also the RHS $(= 1).\ $ That equation follows from the hypothesis that $\,x\,$ is invertible, i.e. $\, xb\equiv 1\pmod{m}\,$ for some $\,b.\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x$ has an inverse modulo $m$. Then for some integer  $y$ we have $xy\equiv 1\pmod{m}$. Thus $xy-1=qm$ for some integer $q$.

Now we show that $\gcd(x,m)=1$. This follows from the fact that $(m)(-q)+(x)(y)=1$. If further details is needed, suppose that $d$ divides $x$ and $m$. Then from $(m)(-q)+(x)(y)=1$ we conclude that $d$ divides $1$. It follows that no $d\gt 1$ can be a common divisor of $x$ and $m$.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This makes a lot of sense to me. However, I don't quite understand d > 1. Does that insure that our inverse is unique?

Comment: You asked for a proof that if $x$ has a unique inverse modulo $m$ then $\gcd(x,m)=1$. I showed that if $x$ has an inverse then $\gcd(x,m)=1$. The uniqueness part was not necessary for the proof.  If you were asked to prove that if $\gcd(x,m)=1$ then $x$ has a unique inverse, we would need to prove both existence and uniqueness. But it seems that the problem does not ask you to prove that $\gcd(x,m)=1$ implies unique inverse. The problem seems to concentrate only on the converse.